# Sql Server Constraint based on two dates difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three columns two are of date types and one is of int

The third column stores the difference between two dates in years.

What could be the constraint for this?

The colums are like:

```
total_years   int           
from_year     datetime  
to_year       datetime
```

The total_years is the difference between two dates(in years)

Comment: Constraint? What are you talking about? You are looking for a constraint on create table in order to check total_years right value? Please, post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) not a constraint

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
  (
     from_year DATETIME,
     to_year   DATETIME,
     total_years AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, from_year, to_year)
  )
```